# Cordova, change name 'www' folder project

Tags: cordova, web, directory, project

I want to copy all the cordoba enviroment in a view of my project, the project name folder is webapp, the problem is, when I try to build with the webapp name, have the error but, when change the name for www, all is ok, is there a way in cordova to change the www name for any other?

P.D. Actually I change the folder name but I want to know if exist the possibility to change the name.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cordova requires the existence of a `www` folder; there is no other way to get around that. You should instead use the parent folder to name the project on disk. As for what the end user will see, use `config.xml` to supply an appropriate name.

Comment: @KerriShotts: You should add your comment as an answer so that the OP can accept it.